# What event should I use to capture error in the insertion in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, events, error-handling, ms-access-2013

I have table with a composite index to avoid duplicate insert duplicates base in the combination of two columns.

Every time that I insert duplicate data i get this message
with this information: "the changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate..."
How can I capture that event an change that message for my custom message. I tried using the form event

```
Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
```

but the it is being triggered after the popup of the image is being render and when I try to close the form

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running a query to see if any records are returned before executing the insert query.  i.e. `SELECT KeyFields WHERE KeyFields = 'the key field values you're going to insert'`.  If no records are returned then your insert query should be good to go.

Comment: Are you executing a query to store the data changes?  Or are you using the builtin features of a bound form to store those changes?

Comment: I am using a built in command button to save the information